# Insert time between two DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table db_mafia.game:

```
CREATE TABLE db_mafia.game (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
date_start datetime NOT NULL,
date_finished datetime NOT NULL,
id_header int(11) NOT NULL,
game_lenght time NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )
    ENGINE = INNODB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 51
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

and I insert in this table data from JAVA

```
   try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_mafia","root","qwerty");

                                    String sql = "INSERT INTO game (date_start, date_finished, id_header, game_lenght) values (?,?,?,?)";
   pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
   pst.setString(1, jTextField2.getText());
   pst.setString(2, jTextField3.getText());
   pst.setString(3, jTextField1.getText());
    pst.setString(4, ?????????);
   pst.execute();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Игра завершена, до новых встреч  " +jLabel1.getText());

   }
```

but I want to insert in column game_lenght  the time between  date_finished and date_start (in minutes). How can I do it? Maybe by using triggers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need to store game length in table if your question is about SQL.

You should be always be able to calculate it when you retrieve the date with SQL query:

```
SELECT t.*, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(date_start , date_finished)) / 60 as game_lenght
FROM myTable t
```

If you want to calculate length of the game outside of the database, then you need to change the tags.